# jQuery/Lodash - Get multiple nested json values by key

Tags: javascript, jquery, lodash

I've got a set of json that's being generated for use with other functions.

```
window.customJSON = {
  "1894873974": {
    title: "Yellow",
    images: [
      {
      main: "/images/img1.jpg",
      alt: "image alt tag"
      },
      {
      main: "/images/img2.jpg",
      alt: "image alt tag"
      }
    ]
  },
  "2397423987": {
    title: "Orange",
    images: [
      {
      main: "/images/img1.jpg",
      alt: "image alt tag"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

What I'm trying to do is get all values of 'main' within 'images' for all items and assign them into a single array. The numbers represent unique codes so I'm not trying to get a specific index but all image urls.

I'm using lodash to successfully map other things so I've tried using:

```
var imgArray = _.map(window.customJSON.images, 'main');
```

I'm just not quite sure the correct syntax. I've looked through the lodash docs and I haven't been able to google the right combination of words to get an answer.

A jquery or lodash solution would both work.

Thanks

Comment: Ur json is incorrect, images should be an object

Comment: There is no JSON in your question, please read [What is the difference between JSON and Object Literal Notation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2904131/what-is-the-difference-between-json-and-object-literal-notation)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to `flatMap` the `images` first, before mapping the `main` attributes. See the working demo below:

```js
let customJSON = {
  "1894873974": {
    title: "Yellow",
    images: [{
        main: "/images/img1.jpg",
        alt: "image alt tag"
      },
      {
        main: "/images/img2.jpg",
        alt: "image alt tag"
      }
    ]
  },
  "2397423987": {
    title: "Orange",
    images: [{
      main: "/images/img1.jpg",
      alt: "image alt tag"
    }]
  }
}

let result = _(customJSON)
  .flatMap('images')
  .map('main')
  .value();

console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.10/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

If you need to get only the unique values, apply `uniq()` before `value()` as well.

Comment: *.values()* is not necessary

Comment: @KoushikChatterjee -- thanks for pointing out. Code corrected.

Answer (score 0):

Loop over object keys and map the images..

```js
let customJSON = {
  "1894873974": {
    title: "Yellow",
    images: [
      {
      main: "/images/img1.jpg",
      alt: "image alt tag"
      },
      {
      main: "/images/img2.jpg",
      alt: "image alt tag"
      }
    ]
  },
  "2397423987": {
    title: "Orange",
    images: [
      {
      main: "/images/img1.jpg",
      alt: "image alt tag"
      }
    ]
  }
}

let res = [];
for(var key in customJSON) {
  let images = customJSON[key]['images'];
  res = res.concat(images.map(image => image.main))
}
console.log(res);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.10/lodash.core.js"></script>
```